# Sqlclient vs EntityClient

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, ado.net

Can any body say the exact difference between sqlclient vs entityclient (sys.data.sqlclient vs sys.data.entityclient)?

Comment: The EntityClient provider is used for accessing data based on an Entity Data Model (EDM). Unlike the other .NET Framework data providers, it does not interact directly with a data source. Instead, it uses Entity SQL to communicate with the underlying data provider. The EntityClient provider exposes generic interfaces for client code and acts as a bridge to other .NET Framework data providers, such as System.Data.SqlClient. If you have to use EntityClient directly, it is easy to code against because it follows the familiar programming patterns found in the other .NET Framework data providers.