# Why are the data providers different for code first and db first with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dataprovider

I'm a newbie for entity framework.

When I added code first and db first entities to my project,
I noticed that code first uses standart sql provider "System.Data.SqlClient"
and db first uses "System.Data.EntityClient" provider.
The classes generated for 2 different type is very similar, actually I did not notice any difference except "OnModelCreating" override from DbContext.

Code first :

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Db First :

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PenCalcEntities" connectionString="" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

1 ) Why is there a difference like that ? And altough the classes very similar , why code first does not work with EntityClient provider , and why db first does not work with SqlClient provider ?

2) Two type of approaches add "entityFramework" section to my config file like

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

When I removed this section , it also works well for two approaches.
What is the purpose of this section ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310183/sqlclient-vs-entityclient

Comment: @SteveGreene that is not an answer to my question.

Comment: When it section not exist in Config EF use Factory provider.